# Missing theme assemblies from AppStore IPA release

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've upgraded to the latest stable Xamarin tools, and since then I'm having problems with missing theme assemblies in my AppStore IPA.  My debug build has all the themes assembly, but as soon as I build my AppStore release build it's missing a bunch of assemblies from my IPA i.e.

[image]

I have the following code to ensure the assembly references are used somewhere, but again the assemblies only appear my debug version and not my AppStore version

`Type x = typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Themes.LightThemeResources);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I may have found a workaround, I simply changed the "init" code, that's used to trick Xamarin to keep those assembly from:

`Type x = typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Themes.LightThemeResources);`

To

`var x = new Xamarin.Forms.Themes.LightThemeResources();`

and the assembly is now in the IPA, I guess something has changed in the last Xamarin release that changes the way that stuff is processed.